# How to check when a user presses the enter key without providing a value in C++

Tags: c++, input, key

In my code, I want to check whether enter key is pressed when input value is not entered. Because, normally pushing enter key just makes new line until unless input is not entered and ;instead, I want it make a command by detecting enter key is pressed in this case.

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <string>
   using namespace std;

   int main(){    
        String str="";
        while(str!="exit"){
          cin>>str;
          if(input is not entered and enter key is pressed)
             continue;
          else
             break;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

I am open to any suggestions.

Comment: Hi Encoder Senjin. I recently encountered this issue and Darien Pardinas’ answer worked for me. If it works for you, you should formally accept it so others can see it. If it doesn’t work, what exactly happens? How did you fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{    
 char str[10];
 char a;
 int i=0;
 cout<<"\nEnter the input :-";
 do{
      a=getche();
      if(a!=13)
        {
         str[i]=a;
         i++;
        }
        else
          break;
   }
   while(a!=13);
   return 0;
}
```

In the above code, getch() is a method that takes a single character input without printing it to the screen. When the input is taken, it is checked with 13, which is the ASCII value for the enter key. If a match is found, it will terminate per your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete example. In short, you can use `getline` from `<string>` and it will give you empty input as well when you hit the `Enter` key.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    while(true)
    {
        std::string in;
        getline(std::cin, in);

        if (in.empty())
        {
            std::cout << "Enter key was pressed with no message" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Enter key was pressed with message" << in << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the character using getch() or any other relative and then compare for the enter key using its ANSCI code which is '\x0D'